# How can I loop through an array and add info into firebase after a fetch request to a server is completed?

Tags: javascript, firebase, fetch-api

I am building an ecommerce site, and I want to update the info in a firebase db when a customer buys a group of items.
so far I learned that to update data in firebase realtime storage I would have to use this

```
    db = firebase.database().ref('details').child(path);
                db.update({
                          stock: amount you want to update to 
                        })
                        }
```

this is helpful but I wanted to update multiple files based on what was bought so I created a function to get the info I need to pass in depending on what I wanted to update, something like this

```
// this is where everything is stored when items() is done doing what it does
var itemsA = {}

function items(arr1, arr2, arr3,arr4){
        arr4 = Object.values(arr4) 
        arr1.forEach((item,index) => {
          itemsA[add++] = {
            1: arr1[index],
            2: arr3[index],
            3: arr4[index]-arr2[index]
          }
        });
    }

//passes values into items() so itemsA can get populated

items(id,quantityA,path,amountInStock)
itemArray = Object.keys(itemsA);
for( let s = 0; s < itemArray.length; s++){ 
    db = firebase.database().ref('details').child(itemsA[s][2]);
                db.update({
                          stock: itemsA[s][3] 
                        })
}
```

if I were to put a value like 4 in place of (itemsA[s][3]) as the update it would work but the second I pass a variable it shows an error what would only occur if it someone ran my request to my api.

Note: the the code takes if a fetch request to the payment api is sucessful.
Any ideas or pointer? thx

Comment: Try to ```console.log(itemsA[s][3])``` and what is ```itemArray``` in your codes?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add, ItemArray is Object.keys(itemArray), I will add that to my post right away and I did console.log(itema[s][3]) it's the value it updated in firestore, which I got from substracting the the amount bought from the amount in stock

Comment: Please fix your codes first. ```itemsA[add++]``` What is ```add``` in your codes?